# Is there a way to get all non null value from a group of columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

Good Day,

I would like to ask, is there a easier way to get a group of columns that are not null?

**Scenario**

I have a uploader which get data from excel. The code is working but gets deadlocked. I would like to revise my code since I'm doing average RBAR (row by agonizing row)

**Code**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[saveProdPropSampDta]
@PartNo as nvarchar(20),
@PPFno as nvarchar(20),
@Dimension as nvarchar(30),
@ToUpdate as nvarchar(10),
@count as nvarchar(2),
@Judgement as nvarchar(2)

as
declare @TSQL as nvarchar(max)
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
begin

--remove spaces from variable @dimension
set @Dimension = REPLACE(@Dimension, ' ','')



--ToUpdate is the value of from Excel

    set @TSQL = 'update ProductProperty set T'+@count+' = @ToUpdate where Partno = @Partno and PPFno = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension';

    exec sp_executesql @TSQL, N'@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20), @Dimension as nvarchar(30), @ToUpdate as nvarchar(10), @count as nvarchar(2)', @PartNo, @PPFno , @Dimension, @ToUpdate, @count;


    declare @cursor CURSOR
    declare @colname as nvarchar(30)
    declare @top as integer
    declare @query as nvarchar(MAX)
    declare @topass as nvarchar(MAX) = ''
    declare @retVal nvarchar(30)
    declare @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) 
        SET @cursor = CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    (select [Name] from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'ProductProperty') and [Name] like 'T%' and [name] <> 'TEMP')order by [Name] asc

    --Gets column names from table from T1 -> T45

    OPEN @cursor

    FETCH NEXT


    FROM @cursor INTO @colname
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @query = N'set @categoryid = (select distinct ' + @colname + ' from ProductProperty 
                    where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension)';
        --


        EXEC sp_executesql @query, 
                    N'@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension 
                    nvarchar(30), @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension, 
                    @categoryid OUTPUT

            if @categoryid is not null
                begin
                    set @topass = @topass + @colname + '+'
                end




    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @cursor INTO @colName
    END

    CLOSE @cursor
    DEALLOCATE @cursor


        set @topass = LEFT(@topass, LEN(@topass)-1)



        set @topass  =  N'set @categoryid = (Select cast(('+@topass+')/'+@count+' as decimal(18,3)) from ProductProperty where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension)';


    EXEC sp_executesql @topass, 
        N'@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension 
        nvarchar(30), @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension, 
        @categoryid OUTPUT

        set @topass = 'update ProductProperty set average = '+@categoryid+', Judgement = '''+@Judgement+''' where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension';




    EXEC sp_executesql @topass, 
        N'@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension 
        nvarchar(30)', @PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension


end
```

---

**Reason for such code**

The code will run each time it is called in the VB.Net code, It will get data from variable into the stored procedure. The code actually gets average from columns that are not null

**What I would like to have**
Is there something like

```
select ave(ifnull(T1.....T2,If Null dont include, ifnot null include)) from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I might go about reworking your solution.

If you are limited in what you can change, then #2 might be the ticket.  But my personal preference would be #1 - the resulting code is simpler, and there are no changes to make if you decide you need a T46.

**Approach number 1:**

You haven't provided full details of your tables, so I'm going to guess that you have an `ID` column that constitutes a primary key, or if not then we'll add one in the new solution :)

I am also going to assume that you are receiving `nvarchar`parameters into your stored proc by necessity rather than by choice, and declare data types accordingly.

Is a redesign of your data model out of the question?  One way to approach this would be to move your "T1".."T45" columns into a separate table and treat them as rows.

You could go from a table of:

```
Create Table ProductProperty 
(
    ID int identity, 
    Partno nvarchar(20), 
    PPFno nvarchar(20), 
    DName nvarchar(30),
    T1 decimal(18, 3),
    T2 decimal(18, 3),
    T3 decimal(18, 3),
--  ...
    T44 decimal(18, 3),
    T45 decimal(18, 3),
    average decimal(18, 3),
    Judgement nvarchar(2)
)
```

to

```
Create Table ProductProperty 
(
    ID int identity, 
    Partno nvarchar(20), 
    PPFno nvarchar(20), 
    DName nvarchar(30),
    average decimal(18, 3),
    Judgement nvarchar(2)
) -- You would probably want to put a unique index on (Partno, PPFno, DName)

Create Table ProductPropertyT
(
    ProductPropertyID int,
    TNo nvarchar(2),
    TValue decimal(18, 3)
)
```

Now your stored procedure simply needs to identify the primary key value (based I surmise on the compound key `Partno`, `PPFno` and `DName`), create or update a record in the `ProductPropertyT` table, and do a simple average over `TValue` for those records with a matching `ProductPropertyId` value:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[saveProdPropSampDta]
@PartNo as nvarchar(20),
@PPFno as nvarchar(20),
@Dimension as nvarchar(30),
@ToUpdate as nvarchar(10),
@count as nvarchar(2),
@Judgement as nvarchar(2)
as
begin

--remove spaces from variable @dimension
set @Dimension = REPLACE(@Dimension, ' ','')

    -- determine the PK
    declare @pk int
    select @pk = ID from ProductProperty where Partno = @Partno and PPFno = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension

    -- create / update the value in the ProductPropertyT table
    if exists (select * from ProductPropertyT where ProductPropertyID = @pk and TNo = @count)
    begin
        update ProductPropertyT 
        set TValue = cast(@ToUpdate as decimal(18, 3))
        where ProductPropertyID = @pk and TNo = @count
    end
    else
    begin 
        insert into ProductPropertyT (ProductPropertyID, TNo, TValue)
        values (@pk, @count, cast(@ToUpdate as decimal(18, 3)))
    end

    -- update the average and judgement in the ProductProperty table.
    update ProductProperty 
       set average = (select avg(TValue) from ProductPropertyT where ProductPropertyID = @pk)
          ,Judgement = @Judgement
     where ID = @pk
end
```

The stored proc is now: shorter; has no dynamic sql; is fairly simple to understand.

**Approach number 2:**

If you absolutely must have this data model, then you could use `unpivot` to get the non-null values from the T1...T45 columns and simply average them.

```
SELECT avg(TValue) 
from 
(   
    -- this will give you only the values for the current part/ppf/dimension
    select * from ProductProperty 
    where Partno = @Partno and PPFno = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension
) myrow
unpivot 
(
    TValue
    for TCol in (T1, T2, ... T44, T45)
) as x
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to weave this into an update statement - but suffice to say you wouldn't need any dynamic sql for this part of your procedure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Never heard of unpivot until today, I used it and the code was faster than before, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this.

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN T1 IS NOT NULL THEN T1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - the average of (3, 3, 0) is 2, the average of (3,3) is 3.